# Microsoft Surface Book1 - Reset Failed

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-installation, microsoft-surface

My Surface Book 1 (Windows 10 / i7 / 256GB) recently stopped charging, both batteries discharged down to zero percent and will only run by being plugged in directly to power. In my attempts to diagnose and fix this I purchased a new charger but this made no difference.

As a last step, following online guidance, I started doing a Windows "reset", so reinstall windows but keep my files. Unfortunately, this appears to have errored partway through the process and could not recover. The boot cycle looks like this:

1. Surface Logo - Please Wait
2. Choose your keyboard layout
3. Troubleshoot

   1. **Start-up Repair** - This goes to "diagnosing your PC", "attempting repairs" and then immediately "Start-up repair couldn't repair your PC" and presents no log information.
   2. **UEFI Firmware Settings** - This goes to the standard Surface UEFI screen. Only unusual thing with this screen is under "Boot configuration" it does not allow the boot order to be changed, although I cannot confirm whether it's always been like this.
   3. **Command Prompt** - This is restricted to the `X:` drive, and I cannot switch to `C:`, I've run various commands such as `diskpart`, `bootrec` etc. but with no success.
   4. **System Restore** - "To use System Restore you must specify which Windows installation to restore. Restart this computer, select an operating system, and then select System Restore" is the only message I get before returning to the troubleshoot menu.
   5. **Uninstall Updates** - "We ran into a problem and won't be able to uninstall the latest quality update of Windows"
   6. **System Image Recovery** - Windows cannot find a system image on this computer. Attach the backup hard disk or insert the final DVD from a backup set and click Retry"
4. Shut down

I've decided to go for the nuclear option and reinstall Windows, downloaded the media creation tool and generated a Windows 10 boot media on USB. Plugged this in and it booted from the USB drive, gave two options:

1. **Repair** - This goes into the above "Troubleshoot" stages with the same outcomes
2. **Install**:

   1. Upgrade - "The upgrade option isn't available if you start your computer using Windows installation media.
   2. Custom - This allows me to choose an install location from the below options. I choose `C:` and accept that it will rename `Windows` to `Windows.old`, it goes through the copying and preparing of Windows files, but it eventually goes to a screen saying the installation was cancelled with an error message - "Windows could not update the computers boot configuration. installation cannot proceed" and that's as far as I can go.

      1. Drive 0 Partition 1: SYSTEM (Total: 260MB, Free: 228MB, Type: System)
      2. Drive 0 Partition 2 (Total: 128MB, Free: 128MB, Type: MSR Reserved)
      3. Drive 0 Partition 3: Local Disk (Total: 237.1GB, Free: 39.2GB, Type: Primary)
      4. Drive 0 Partition 4: Windows RE tools (Total: 1020MB, Free: 388MB, Type: Recovery)

I'm fast running out of options as every pathway seems to lead to an error of some kind. I'm considering removing partitions from the installation pathway, but am unsure as to which would be safe to remove.

Has anybody had this issue, or can you recommend steps to resolve?

Comment: When batteries die they die. A new charger won't make any difference nor any OS/software.

Comment: I appreciate the fact that batteries can die, albeit it unusual that both batteries (Surface Book has one in the tablet part and another in the keyboard) should die at the same time, and that the powercfg battery report shows that the batteries still have cycles in them and is still able to access information about them. What I'm more seeking guidance on is how to get the laptop back to life with regard to Windows even just running directly off the mains for now.

Comment: The fact the installation is failing suggests a problem with the SSD. You have nothing to lose by deleting the partitions. The clean install already failed so your existing installation was already wiped.

Comment: Ok thanks. Would you delete all partitions, or just certain ones from those that I listed?